ImportError: cannot import name 'RSAAlgorithm' from 'jwt.algorithms'
The RSAAlgorithm PyJWT algorithm method fails to import, but I do have the PyJWT installed.
Error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'RSAAlgorithm' from 'jwt.algorithms'

I checked if the package is available by running this command:
poetry show|grep -i pyjwt

pyjwt                         2.9.0        JSON Web Token implementation in...


This question is similar to: PyJWT won't import jwt.algorithms (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt.algorithms'). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. (It's not a precise dupe, but the highest-voted answer still applies.)

I needed to additionally install the cryptography Python package.
# Poetry
poetry add cryptography

# OR PIP
pip install cryptography

After this I was able to successfully import the method.
